# Jquery each toggleClass

Tags: jquery, each, toggleclass

So, i'm using a foreach that generates "li's" in a menu. Currently there are only two "li's". This menu becomes thiner when you click on a button and i wanted to decrease the font-size when this happens.

I've tried using the toggleClass() function inside an each() function to do this but only the first "li" toggles the class, the second remais the same.

```
foreach ($results as $result){
                       $local = $result['local'];
                   echo "<li><a class='clsPostData1' data-local='".$result['local']."' data-salaid='".$result['salaid']."' data-salakey='".$result['salakey']."'href='#'><span id='idfontsala'>".$local."</span></a></li>";
                   }
```

I'm using the "idfontsala" ID inside a span.

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function(){
    $('#idfontsala').each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('classfontsala');
    });
  });
});

  </script>
```

This is what is happening : https://i.imgsafe.org/34d4f934b5.png

Comment: I noticed you are using an id for your $.each method. By practice html ids are unique, which means this could be your issue. May we see your markup?

Comment: Never mind, I found your id. try using a class instead of an id.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()`. You can just use `$('selector').toggleClass('classname')` and it will toggle all of them. But as @PeterClark said, you need to use a class rather than an ID to match multiple elements.

Comment: Yes, the id was the problem, it worked as soons as i changed to a class. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all generated items to be affected. Use a class to match multiple elements. Replace your markup with:

```
 <span class='fontsala'>
```

And your script with:

```
 $('.fontsala').each(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('classfontsala');
});
```

UPDATE:

This is if you still want to use $.each. But as @Barmar said, it can be shortened.

```
$('.fontsala').toggleClass('classfontsala');
```